# How to configure Apache Beam job to use Spark runner from Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-beam, databricks

I am used to write Spark pipeline directly on Databricks. I switch to write Apache Beam job, My pipline works well with Direct runner and local Spark runner.

Now I want to configure my beam job to use my existing Databrick Spark cluster, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: hi, I believe that this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-an-apache-beam-data-pipeline-on-azure-databricks-c09e521d8fc3) might be useful in your case

Comment: Hi @FranVerdejo, Thanks for the article. I saw it before. However, I use beam python API and this article does not seem to mention how to configure spark master in beam pipeline.

Comment: On which Cloud platform are you trying to achieve this? Also, do you have a code snippet you could add to the description about what you are trying it?